# Prove that the function $f(x,y) = ax + by$ is onto

Tags: functions, divisibility

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and have gotten stuck. This is a homework question so I just require some hints to push me to the answer.

Question:
Let $a, b$ be integers. Consider the following function:

$$ f : \mathbb{Z} \space \times \space \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}  $$

such that for any $(x, y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},\space f(x, y) = ax + by. $

Give a simple condition on $a$ and $b$, and then prove the proposition.

Proposition 1. The function $f$ is onto if and only if .........

**Reasoning:**
The function needs to cover all the possible coordinates. So we can see that if we let $a = 4, b = 8$ then all the real coordinates are not being covered by $f(x,y) = ax + by$ since all the coordinates are multiples. So $a$ and $b$ cannot be multiples of each other. We can assert this condition by letting $a$ and $b$ be co-primes. So we can say $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

**�Attempt:**
Since this is an if and only if proof, we need to show that:

A. If $f$ is onto, then $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

B. If $gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $f$ is onto.

Proof of A: 
Lets assume that $f$ is onto. By that assumption we can say that:

$\forall \space m \in \mathbb{Z}, \space \exists \space (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \space \times \space \mathbb{Z}$, such that $f(x,y) = m$

Let $m = ax + by$ since $ax+by \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So from that we have $f(x,y) = ax+by$

**More of the proof:**

Since $f(x,y) = ax+by$ is onto, we know that there must be a point where $ax+by = 1$ (by definition of onto).

$$ax + by = 1$$

$$\implies gcd (a,b) = 1$$

Proof of B:
Leb $gcd(a,b) = 1$. From that, we know that $ax+by = 1$. We must show that:

$\forall \space ax+by \in \mathbb{Z}, \space \exists \space (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \space \times \space \mathbb{Z}$, such that $f(x,y) = ax + by$

**�Attempt:** Can I say that since $gcd (a,b) = 1$, it always maps to an integer?

Comment: Have you already learned Bezout's identity for the gcd?

Comment: Oh yea, now that I see the definition, I have learned it. I also believe that I applied it correctly in the above proof.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is onto you can find $x,y$ with $ax+by=1$ (because $f$ has to hit $1$ to be onto) - can you go from there?

Comment: Yes, I will try to push my solution from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** to complement Mark Bennet's **hint** (Down vote this if It's too much or wrong):

If $\gcd(a,b) \neq 1$ then there exists $j,k,c \in \mathbb{Z}, c > 1$ such that $b=kc,a=jc$. Therefore:
$$ax+by=jcx+kcy=c(jx+ky)$$